# Como adicionar parâmetros no TDFQuerry

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Como adicionar um novo parâmetro no `TDFQuerry`?, 
A imagem abaixo mostra os parâmetros preenchido, e no caso preciso saber como adicionar outro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

A adição de parâmetros é adicionado automaticamente baseado no
script escrito na aba `SQL Command`

Veja este Exemplo:

```
SELECT IDADE, SEXO, ETC 
  FROM PACIENTES
 WHERE PACIENTE = :PACIENTE
   AND NOME     = :NOME
```

Seguindo este exemplo será apresentado os 2 parâmetros, `PACIENTE` e `NOME`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

Para este caso, basta adicionar no corpo do comando SQL (aba SQL command) o nome dos parâmetros desejados. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTE WHERE ID1 = :PARAM1 and ID2 = :PARAM2
```

Respeitando essa nomenclatura, o próprio Firedac se responsabiliza por incluir os novos parâmetros, cabendo a você especificar as demais informações dos mesmos (tipo, tamanho, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Há duas formas de se fazer isso:

Uma é de forma estática, informando na propriedade `Params` do data set.

A outra é através de linha de código mesmo, através do comando `FDQuery.ParamByName('INFORME_O_SEU_PARAMETRO')`.

Eu particularmente gosto mais da segunda, fico menos preso à configuração do data set.